# How to flag last inserted or updated entries as 'active'

Tags: postgresql

I am setting up a database for a auction house tracking tool. The raw data consists of an array of offers. With each update of the API it will return only the currently active offers. What is the preferred way to design a table which reflects the active orders while keeping a history of offers, ideally making it possible to get the timestamp of first occurrence and a "last seen" flag?

My first idea was to update all entries as "inactive" which are not part of the current insert query, but this approach seems to be really inefficient.

Comment: Have a table for the offers, one row per offer including a timestamp or another ordinal. Then you have the history and can always select the row with the highest ordinal to get the last offer.

Comment: If the current array of offers returned by the API contains an already existing offer I update the timestamp or ordinal, right? Thank you

Comment: No, you don't update. And you don't use arrays. At least in the table. You just collect offers, row for row.

Comment: Posting the API response payload(s) would increase your chances of a quality answer.

Comment: +1 This is an issue that I would be interested as well. Some optimization for the "most recent" problem without having to issue separate queries for the "now" and the "historic" entries.

Comment: Thank you for your answers so far. I will update with a response of the API asap.

Answer (score 1):

As this is something I find interesting, I have created an example structure which might be far from perfect but may be a starting point.

**WARNING**: This will only work with PostgreSQL 11+ due to the new [default partitions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-PARTITION)

## TL;DR

Online example with tests and data results: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=65e90f7ce5fc606c0ecde03fc44bf333

## Long version

Structure explained:

### 1. The auction table

```sql
CREATE TABLE auction (
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    title text NOT NULL,
    bid_min numeric(18,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00,
    start_time timestamptz NOT NULL,
    end_time timestamptz NOT NULL
);

CREATE INDEX idx_auction_open ON auction USING gist (id, tstzrange(start_time, end_time));
```

Here, I've basically just started with a bare minimum but at least accounted for active vs. closed auctions. This is why there is a `GIST` index:

#### Index idx_auction_open

This will make sure that a query to fetch all currently active (or open at any point in time) will be returned very fast, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT * FROM auction WHERE tstzrange(start_time, end_time) @> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Plan (for a few thousand auctions):

```
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using idx_auction_open on auction  (cost=0.28..5.83 rows=3 width=38) (actual time=0.048..0.049 rows=2 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (tstzrange(start_time, end_time) @> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
   Buffers: shared hit=4
 Planning Time: 0.151 ms
 Execution Time: 0.069 ms
(5 rows)
```

In addition, it also helps for the trigger function which needs to check whether the referenced auction exists and is actually still open with the following query:

```sql
SELECT bid_min INTO minimum FROM auction WHERE id = NEW.auction_id AND tstzrange(start_time, end_time) @> NEW.bid_time;
```

Example execution plan:

```
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Scan using idx_auction_open on auction  (cost=0.15..2.37 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.042..0.043 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((id = 1) AND (tstzrange(start_time, end_time) @> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP))
   Buffers: shared hit=3
 Planning Time: 0.156 ms
 Execution Time: 0.072 ms
(5 rows)
```

### 2. The auction_bids table

```sql
CREATE TABLE auction_bids (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    auction_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES auction(id),
    bid numeric(18,2) NOT NULL,
    bid_time timestamptz NOT NULL,
    replaced_by integer
) PARTITION BY LIST (replaced_by);

CREATE TABLE auction_bids_active PARTITION OF auction_bids FOR VALUES IN (NULL);
CREATE TABLE auction_bids_history PARTITION OF auction_bids DEFAULT;

CREATE INDEX idx_auction_bids_id ON auction_bids (id);
CREATE INDEX idx_auction_bids_active ON auction_bids (auction_id, user_id, bid_time) WHERE (replaced_by IS NULL);
CREATE INDEX idx_auction_bids_historic ON auction_bids (auction_id, user_id, bid_time DESC) WHERE (replaced_by IS NOT NULL);
```

Here, I actually made use of the new PostgreSQL 11 functionality for default partitions where the default partition `auction_bids_history` holds all historic auction bids and the other partition `auction_bids_active` is configured to only contain the bids that are the latest.

This creates a nice setup to provide a hint for PostgreSQL for partition pruning (which partitions to actually scan) and as we expect the history partition to grow much faster than the active one.

E.g. here is the execution plan of a query for all active auctions and their active bids:

```sql
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT a.title, b.user_id, b.bid, b.bid_time
FROM auction_bids AS b INNER JOIN auction AS a ON (a.id = b.auction_id)
WHERE replaced_by IS NULL AND tstzrange(a.start_time, a.end_time) @> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ORDER BY auction_id, bid DESC, user_id;
```

```
                                                               QUERY PLAN                                                                
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=5.69..5.70 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.117..0.118 rows=2 loops=1)
   Sort Key: b.auction_id, b.bid DESC, b.user_id
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
   Buffers: shared hit=4
   ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.20..5.68 rows=1 width=33) (actual time=0.100..0.104 rows=2 loops=1)
         Hash Cond: (a.id = b.auction_id)
         Buffers: shared hit=4
         ->  Index Scan using idx_auction_open on auction a  (cost=0.15..4.60 rows=3 width=14) (actual time=0.066..0.067 rows=1 loops=1)
               Index Cond: (tstzrange(start_time, end_time) @> CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
               Buffers: shared hit=3
         ->  Hash  (cost=1.03..1.03 rows=2 width=23) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=2 loops=1)
               Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB
               Buffers: shared hit=1
               ->  Append  (cost=0.00..1.03 rows=2 width=23) (actual time=0.014..0.017 rows=2 loops=1)
                     Buffers: shared hit=1
                     ->  Seq Scan on auction_bids_active b  (cost=0.00..1.02 rows=2 width=23) (actual time=0.013..0.015 rows=2 loops=1)
                           Filter: (replaced_by IS NULL)
                           Buffers: shared hit=1
 Planning Time: 0.696 ms
 Execution Time: 0.182 ms
(20 rows)
```

*(the sequential scan is totally OK here for now)*

I've also added some helper indexes which might get useful with higher number of bids especially for searching the previous active entry by the trigger function, e.g.:

```sql
SELECT * INTO previous_bid
            FROM auction_bids
            WHERE
                replaced_by IS NULL
                AND
                auction_id = NEW.auction_id
                AND
                user_id = NEW.user_id
            ORDER BY bid_time DESC
            LIMIT 1;
```

Example execution plan:

```
                                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                                           
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.15..2.38 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.022..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=2
   ->  Merge Append  (cost=0.15..2.38 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.020..0.020 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: auction_bids_active.bid_time DESC
         Buffers: shared hit=2
         ->  Index Scan Backward using auction_bids_active_auction_id_user_id_bid_time_idx on auction_bids_active  (cost=0.14..2.36 rows=1 width=44) (actual time=0.018..0.019 rows=1 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((auction_id = 1) AND (user_id = 123))
               Buffers: shared hit=2
 Planning Time: 0.468 ms
 Execution Time: 0.079 ms
(10 rows)
```

### 3. Trigger for rule enforcement

Now, in order to really make a benefit out of the above I've created a trigger function that does basically 3 things:

1. verify that the referenced auction exists, is currently active and that the new bid has a value at least that of the auction minimum
2. verify that the new bid is higher than the existing one (if one exists)
3. move the existing entry (if one exists) to the history partition by setting the `replaced_by` field (this is also new in PostgreSQL 11)

After that trigger finishes, the new record is actually inserted into the `auction_bids_active` partition (because of the `NULL` value for `replaced_by`).

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_auction_bid_check()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    minimum numeric(18,2);
    previous_bid auction_bids%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    NEW.bid_time := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    NEW.replaced_by := NULL;

    SELECT bid_min INTO minimum FROM auction WHERE id = NEW.auction_id AND tstzrange(start_time, end_time) @> NEW.bid_time;
    IF (NOT FOUND) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'No (open) auction available for ID % @ %', NEW.auction_id, NEW.bid_time;
    ELSIF (minimum > NEW.bid) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'New bid must be higher than auction minimum of %: %', minimum, NEW.bid;
    ELSE
        SELECT * INTO previous_bid
            FROM auction_bids
            WHERE
                replaced_by IS NULL
                AND
                auction_id = NEW.auction_id
                AND
                user_id = NEW.user_id
            ORDER BY bid_time DESC
            LIMIT 1;

        IF FOUND THEN
            IF previous_bid.bid >= NEW.bid THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'New bid must be higher than previous: % >= %', previous_bid.bid, NEW.bid;
            END IF;

            UPDATE auction_bids SET replaced_by = NEW.id WHERE id = previous_bid.id;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$;

CREATE TRIGGER trg_auction_bids
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON auction_bids_active
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE func_auction_bid_check()
;
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks. But I dont understand why you have `user_id = NEW.user_id`. Does this not mean that only the previous bidder can bid?

Comment: This may not be 100% perfect, but certainly gives you an idea of what you can do with a "BEFORE INSERT" trigger. I have not looked at newer versions of PostgreSQL whether there is a more out-of-the-box variant to accomplish the same with less overhead.

Comment: Thank you. I've learned a lot from this example.